Image field thumbnail in custom JSON disappearing on publishing of the page
I have a custom tile view for a list containing information of all people. In this view, I want to have a thumbnail of the user's profile picture. This picture is uploaded in the list in the column of image type with the name "Picture".
This view works fine when I'm still on the list itself. Also, when I embed the list with the custom view in a page, it displays the images. However, as soon as I publish this page, the images disappear. This seems like a bug, but maybe I am doing something wrong.
    {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/tile-formatting.schema.json",
  "height": 90,
  "width": "200",
  "hideSelection": false,
  "fillHorizontally": true,
  "formatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "style": {
      "padding-left": "5px",
      "text-align": "center",
      "vertical-align": "middle",
      "border-radius": "10px",
      "border": "1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)",
      "overflow": "hidden"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "style": {
          "text-align": "center",
          "vertical-align": "middle",
          "display": "flex",
          "align-items": "center",
          "height": "90px",
          "width": "90px"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "img",
            "style": {
              "display": "=if([$Picture] == '', 'none', '')",
              "border-radius": "50%",
              "width": "80px",
              "height": "80px"
            },
            "attributes": {
              "src": "[$Picture.serverRelativeUrl]",
              "title": "[$Picture.fileName]",
              "class": "sp-card-imagePreview"
            }
          },
          {
            "elmType": "svg",
            "style": {
              "display": "=if([$Picture] == '', '', 'none')",
              "border-radius": "50%",
              "width": "80px",
              "height": "80px"
            },
            "attributes": {
              "preserveAspectRatio": "none",
              "viewBox": "0 0 210 105",
              "class": "sp-card-defaultImage ms-bgColor-themeLighter"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "path",
                "attributes": {
                  "id": "sp-card-defaultImage-path1",
                  "d": "M0 25.7896L126.5 53.8817L96 105H0V25.7896Z"
                },
                "style": {
                  "fill": "#d2e0f2"
                }
              },
              {
                "elmType": "path",
                "attributes": {
                  "id": "sp-card-defaultImage-path2",
                  "d": "M96 105L158.7 0H204C207.314 0 210 2.68629 210 6V105H96Z"
                },
                "style": {
                  "fill": "#cedbed"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "style": {
          "display": "flex",
          "flex-direction": "column",
          "width": "120px"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "span",
            "style": {
              "font-weight": "bold"
            },
            "txtContent": "=if([$Title]=='', '–', [$Title])"
          },
          {
            "elmType": "span",
            "txtContent": "=if([$FirstName]=='', '', [$FirstName])"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}


Are attachments enabled for your list? If yes, check this JSON sample which shows how to get the correct image URL: Download Image from SharePoint Image column using JSON formatting. Let me know if it works for you.
